# How to split data in a text file in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

.This is how my data looks: name: abcsurname: abctel:1234 and I want it to look like:name: abc and surname: abc should go in the next line.

```
        public void SeparateData()
        {
            //read file
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myTextFile.txt");
            //string to hold line
            string myline;
            myline = sr.ReadLine();
            while ((myline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] lines = Regex.Split(myline, " ");
                foreach (string s in lines)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myTextFile.txt"))
                        sw.WriteLine(lines);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is each "person" on their own line in the file, and does every person have the same info stored (name, surname and telephone) ?

Comment: Could you paste a more comprehensive example of what your data looks like and what you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the each field value flows straight onto the next field name, without any delimiter?

Comment: You might want to use the File.ReadAllLines() method as it will return a string[] array of all lines in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need regex to do a string split on a space, but I don't that is going to get you want you want either way. I am assuming that "abc" stands in for actual values of varying length?

I think you just need to pull out your regex book and split up the string and rewrite it.

e.g. '(name: )(\w*?)(surname: )(\w*?)(tel: )(\d*)' and then just re-assemble and re-write the line using the capturing groups.

I think what you have will give you:

name:
abcsurname:
abctel:
1234

Comment: My data looks like this

Name: abcdSurname: abcdTel: 123456Name: defgSurname:defgTel:45678

and I want it to look like this,
Name: abcd
Surname:abcd
Tel:12345
(skip a line here,then)
Name:defgs
Surname:gdheydh
Tel:8890

Comment: Thank u guys...I've sorted out my problem!!